# Which option is fast to call list

Tags: sharepoint

Can u please explain me which is fast and why or any other option to fast call any list

1) web.GetList(String.Format("{0}/Lists/{1}/AllItems.aspx", web.Url, listname))

2) web.lists[listname]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its impossible to really know without digging out reflector and profiling tools since the documentation doesn't tell us but generally you would expect the 1st to be more efficient.

The reason is that [SPWeb.GetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) is getting one SPList object from SharePoint.

However web.lists is getting a [SPListCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466704.aspx) containing ALL lists in the web and you are then finding the one you want with [listName] (see overloaded [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.item.aspx) property)